# How to pronounce "urethra"?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

I'm confused how to pronounce "urethra". I looked up in the dictionary, it's | jʊˈriːθrə |. Shouldn't it be pronounced "yu-ri-ther"? Many YouTube videos pronounced it "yu-ri-thra".

Comment: I'm confused about the ending sound. Those YouTube videos sounded more -thra than -thruh for me. Or is it because of my ears?

Comment: @Ken You can't use English spelling to convey sounds. You need IPA.

Comment: I think it's probably the American accent. Using IPA symbols, some Americans tend to substitute /ʌ/ for /ə/ at the ends of words. (And other Americans pronounce /ʌ/ and /ə/ exactly the same, except that /ə/ is unstressed.)

Comment: @PeterShor Right, the amount of reduction varies in unstressed syllables. Consider *Sarah* or *Anna*, or *roma* tomatoes on *pizza*.

Comment: the enunciation tools on the web are very good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard physicians (Northeast United States) pronounce it yuh-REE-thruh, which is how I also pronounce it. (The "uh" is a diminished vowel sound, as a schwa and as indicated by your dictionary's pronunciation.)

Comment: "Ureter" is | jʊˈriːtə, ˈjʊərɪtə |. Do ureter and urethra sound the same except /t/ and /thr/?

Comment: @Ken No, *ureter* /jʊˈritər/ ends in a schwa **plus an R**, while *urethra* /jʊˈriθrə/ ends in an R plus a schwa.  See the difference? The ordering of the two final phonemes in the opposite  of each other.

Comment: @tchrist: The OP probably speaks in a British accent, where the /r/ at the end of *ureter* is not pronounced.

Comment: @PeterShor It’s a linking-R then, as in *the ureter and other accoutrements*.

Comment: Yes, I quoted the pronunciation from the Oxford British English Dictionary. These two words have no ending r sound. On Oxford Dictionary website, I found out that these -ter (from ureter) and -thruh (from urethra) sounded more closely than -thraa (urethra) that I heard before on YouTube and Forvo.

Comment: @Ken: I think it's the difference between American English and British English.